# Deploying lambda applications on AWS

Tags: node.js, deployment, aws-lambda

I am writing AWS Lambda functions for my project (node) and now trying to figure out the best way to deploy these.  Ideally I would want to

1. Convert the ES7 code into a version lambda can understand possibly using webpack.
2. Deploy using a command line tool or some npm package.

What is the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`serverless`](https://serverless.com/framework/) and [`serverless-webpack`](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) to do both of those.

`serverless` is a deployment and configuration tool.

`serverless-webpack` is a plugin for `serverless` that will compile your ES7 code upon deployment.

Comment: Serverless seems promising, is this something that is used in common?

Comment: It's the most popular tool for AWS Lambda currently.

Comment: @tmpdev You can mark it as answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Either you canzip it and upload it or you can use automate the deployment with AWS CodePipelne. Please see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html) more details about automated deployment